# Variadic typelist parameter pack expansion

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm trying to create a typelist using variadic templates, which won't require writing a typedef for every length of typelist. I could only come up with the (non-compiling) code below, which hopefully gives an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. Is this approach workable, or is there a better way?

```
#include <tuple>

struct NullType
{
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct TypeListParamPackExpander
{
    using U = TypeList<std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Ts...>>, ...>;
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct TypeList
{
    using Head = T;
    using Tail = TypeListParamPackExpander<Ts...>;
};

template <typename T>
struct TypeList<T, void>
{
    using Head = T;
    using Tail = NullType;
};
```

EDIT:

The intended usage is in a "Scatter Hierarchy". I'm reading Andrei Alexandrescu's book. Here is how it's usage should look:

```
template <template <typename M> typename B, class TList>
class ScatterHierarchy;

template <template <typename M> typename B, class T1, class... Ts>
class ScatterHierarchy<B, TypeList<T1, Ts...>>
    : public ScatterHierarchy<B, T1>
    , public ScatterHierarchy<B, TypeListParamPackExpander<Ts...>>
{
public:
    using TList = TypeList<T1, Ts...>;
    using LeftBase = ScatterHierarchy<B, T1>;
    using RightBase = ScatterHierarchy<B, TypeListParamPackExpander<Ts...>>;
};

template <template <typename> typename B, typename AtomicType>
class ScatterHierarchy: public B<AtomicType>
{
    using LeftBase = B<AtomicType>;
};

template <template <typename M> typename B>
class ScatterHierarchy<B, NullType>
{
};

struct Message1
{
    uint32_t x = 5;
};

struct Message2
{
    float f = 0.123;
};

struct Message3
{
    std::string s = "hello!";
};

template <typename Msg>
struct Holder
{
    Msg message_;
};
int main(void)
{
    using MyScatterHierarchy = ScatterHierarchy<Holder, TypeList<Message1, Message2, Message3>>;

    MyScatterHierarchy a;

    std::cout << static_cast<Holder<Message1>>(a).message_.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << static_cast<Holder<Message2>>(a).message_.f << std::endl;
    std::cout << static_cast<Holder<Message3>>(a).message_.s << std::endl;
};
```

Comment: Your goal is not really clear. What would an example usage look like? Why do you need a specialization of `TypeList<T, void>` instead of just `TypeList<T>`?

Comment: How do you want to use this type list?  Are you going to be querying by index?

Comment: If you want to convert `tuple<A, B, C>` into `TypeList<A, B, C>`, you can just leave generic case of `TupleToList` empty and specialize `TupleToList<tuple<Ts...>>` to return `TypeList<Ts...>`

Comment: I added an example of how this typelist would be used. I avoided doing that at first, because the usage is also quite complex.

Comment: I don't understand the point, or the implementation, of `TypeListParamPackExpander`. For one thing, it defines a member type `U` that absolutely noting in the rest of the code refers to - what is the significance of it? It almost seems like you just want `TypeList<Ts...>` everywhere you are currently using `TypeListParamPackExpander<Ts...>`

Comment: That was just intended as a meaningless placeholder. I came up with a solution, which I'll post. I get that the question is a bit vague though - I should have just went back to the fundamentals of variadic class templates before posting. Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution after finding a solution to a similar problem (the "Tuple" implementation in "C++ templates the complete guide"). Appreciate the comments.

```
struct NullType
{
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct TypeList;

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct TypeList<Head, Tail...>
{
    using H = Head;
    using T = TypeList<Tail...>;
};

template <typename Head>
struct TypeList<Head>
{
    using H = Head;
    using T = NullType;
};

template<>
struct TypeList<>
{};
```

Comment: Wonder why you need `NullType`. Why is `TypeList<OneType>::T` not simply `TypeList<>`? That would have worked out naturally if you simply omit the special case for one type.